# Remove "Add or Remove Buttons" in Rad Command Bar

Tags: winforms, telerik

I have a Rad Command Bar created with the code below:

```
RadCommandBar main = new RadCommandBar();
main.Dock = DockStyle.Top;
main.AutoSize = true;
main.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(874, 59);

CommandBarRowElement address = new CommandBarRowElement();
CommandBarStripElement strip = new CommandBarStripElement();
strip.FloatingForm = null;
strip.StretchHorizontally = true;
address.Strips.Add(strip);

CommandBarDropDownList addressEdit = new CommandBarDropDownList();
addressEdit.MaxSize = new System.Drawing.Size(0, 0);
addressEdit.VisibleInOverflowMenu = true;
addressEdit.StretchHorizontally = true;

main.Rows.Add(address);

parent.Controls.Add(main);
```

I'm having issue with hiding the "Add or Remove Buttons" of the strip element. Can someone point me to the right way to hide that menu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following code:

```
strip.OverflowButton.Visibility = Telerik.WinControls.ElementVisibility.Hidden;
```

Answer (score 1):

It it better to set the Visibility to Collapsed, in order to collapse the whole item. Using Hidden will hide the item, but its space will be retained. More information is available here: [Customize the overflow button](http://www.telerik.com/help/winforms/commandbar-howto-customize-the-overflow-button.html)